# VBA: keep row if specific values exists

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm working on my first VBA script and working from the example found here http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win001.htm

This seems to work well for DELETING rows that meets the criteria "ron", "Dave", "Jelle", but I want to make the code so it KEEPS rows such as "Ron A", "ron B", "C RON", "dave A", "DAVE b" and deletes the rest. In other words, I want to make it not case specific, not order specific, and keep instead of delete.

input:

- Ron A
- george h
- ron B
- C RON
- dave A
- john f
- JIM R

output:

- Ron A
- ron B
- C RON
- dave A

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Delete_with_Autofilter_Array()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim calcmode As Long
    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim I As Long

    With Application
        calcmode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Fill in the values that you want to delete
    myArr = Array("ron", "Dave", "Jelle")

    For I = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

        'Sheet with the data, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
        With ActiveSheet

            'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
            .AutoFilterMode = False

            'Apply the filter
            .Range("A1:A" & .Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myArr(I)

            Set rng = Nothing
            With .AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
            End With

            'Remove the AutoFilter
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With

    Next I

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = calcmode
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Personally, I would use the `Advanced Filter` to "keep" the rows, since you cannot have more than two criteria in an `AutoFilter`.  But you could adapt the method you have as an exercise.  One method would be to capture those rows in a `Collection object`, and then write the `Collection` back to the worksheet.  You'd have to make some changes that would be significant for a newbie, if your table has more than one column.